# How to add 1 year to date stored as varchar?

Tags: mysql

How can add 1 year to a date value stored in the DB as varchar (format: "2011.03")?

I'm trying with this, but returns NULL :(

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('2011.03', '%Y.%m'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR),'%Y.%m')
```

Thank you very much!

edit.: this is the query i want to use in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table WHERE column  BETWEEN '2011.03' AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('2011.03', '%Y.%m'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR),'%Y.%m') ORDER BY column  DESC
```

("2011.03" is a parameter value and comes outside)

Comment: it's working.Try SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('2011.03', '%Y.%m'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR),'%Y.%m')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying is giving correct result

Try :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('2011.03', '%Y.%m'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR),'%Y.%m')
```

it's giving `2012.03`.

**Edit:**

You can use below trick to make it workable in mysql version > 5.0

Add month with date because in Mysql version > 5.0 `str_to_date()` sometimes would return NULL if the %D format specifier was not the last specifier in the format string input.

Try below:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('2011.03.01', '%Y.%m.%d'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR),'%Y.%m')
```

Comment: The result is good, but what is the test query you are testing with? My returns NULL... And in the query iwant to use it's still not working... see modified question

Comment: make sure you have records in this interval. I tried same query with test data here and it's working

Comment: In this interval i have records, i checked it. Strange... And the SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('2011.03', '%Y.%m'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR),'%Y.%m') still returns me NULL :S

Comment: might be we are using different mysql version I have 5.0

Comment: my version is: 5.1.49-3-log (select version();)

Comment: Yes It's version problem.You are right. I tried same with mysql5.5 giving null

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem! :)